# XSLT Display all text Between XML tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am new to using XSLT and I am struggling with a problem . I want to print out the text between the xml tags.

XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<generic-cv:generic-cv xmlns:generic-cv="http://www.cihr-irsc.gc.ca/generic-cv/1.0.0" lang="en" dateTimeGenerated="2014-05-30 11:40:50">
<section id="f589cbc028c64fdaa783da01647e5e3c" label="Personal Information">
    <section id="2687e70e5d45487c93a8a02626543f64" label="Identification" recordId="4f7c2ebd789f407b939e05664f6aa7c0">
        <field id="ee8beaea41f049d8bcfadfbfa89ac09e" label="Title">
            <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000318">Mr.</lov>
        </field>
        <field id="5c6f17e8a67241e19667815a9e95d9d0" label="Family Name">
            <value type="String">ali</value>
        </field>
        <field id="98ad36fee26a4d6b8953ea764f4fed04" label="First Name">
            <value type="String">Hara</value>
        </field>
        <field id="4ca83c1aaa6a42a78eac0290368e70f3" label="Middle Name">
            <value type="String"/>
        </field>
        <field id="41ed5ea3ae974428b3fcb592161b6423" label="Date of Birth">
            <value format="MM/dd" type="MonthDay">8/23</value>
        </field>
        <field id="2b72a344523c467da0c896656b5290c0" label="Correspondence language">
            <lov id="00000000000000000000000000000054">English</lov>
        </field>
    </section>
</section>
```

xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Xml Convertor</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h2><b> Personal Information</b></h2>
              <ul>
                    <li>Name:</li>
                    <li> Date of Birth:</li>
                    <li> Language:</li>

                  </ul>         

        </body>
        </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

what i have tried using so far is

```
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(parent::*),'> ',.,'&#xA;')"/>
```

but this will print out all the info between the tags

I would like the the output to be like

```
Name: Hara ali
Date of Birth: 8/23 
Language: English
```

How can I do this with xslt?

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried that does not work? What output do you get that's different from what you want?  Your XSL contains an unmatched `<ul>` tag... is that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text from a node can be received by using `xsl:value-of`, you will want to select the fields by their label,  something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//field[@label='First Name']/value" />
```

You should be able to get the rest by yourself.